# Platform-specific User-controls

Tags: c#, xamarin, user-controls, xamarin.forms

Hello all great people in here

I am heading for creation of a Xamarin.Forms app.

I have taken a look on this link https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/entry/, where they are going to make the renderer for components platform-specific. 
An example can be TwinTechs Controls, which is only available for iOS and Android. How can this be done?

Is that possible? And if it, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Renderer` class is the custom platform-specific that you need to customize per platform.

In that particular example they are looking at changing an existing renderer.

You will be more focused in writing your own platform-specific components from scratch.

To do so you will want to inherit from `ViewRenderer` and supply reference to the `View` and also the platform-specific `native` element that will be the root of the control on the platform level.

Don't forget to export the renderer also, for it to be used in the rendering process of the page in `Xamarin.Forms`, from the platform level along the lines:-

```
[assembly: ExportRendererAttribute(typeof({ViewNameHere}), typeof({RendererClassNameHere}))]
```

There is a useful tutorial on writing custom renderers [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/videos/cross-platform/xamarinforms-custom-renderers/) that will help you further.

Comment: Pete I have done all my user-interface in the portable, but now I e.g. have to use FastCell from TwinTechs. But it is only available for iOS and Android. How can I make this possible?

Comment: @The87Boy Do you want to quickly add me on messenger and I can get down to the specific answer quicker than messaging on here?  If so my contact details are on my profile.

Comment: Your need to go into NuGet and ensure you have the Microsoft.Bcl.Build package installed.  Check the references, there maybe some others not there also.  You may want to try loading up the solution file separately and trying to compile that way first.

Comment: @The87Boy If you want `FastCell` Have you looked at `ListViewCachingStrategy` that is in the latest Xamarin.Forms platform

Comment: @The87Boy user1 is right to look at the ListViewCachingStrategy which is now available on all platforms. George Cook who created those renderers initially did so before this feature came out in XF. There is no longer any need to use those specific controls.

Comment: @AdamPedley His original question was relating to custom renderers in general and didn't mention anything with regard to the TwinTech renderers initially.  I'll be chatting with him tomorrow to hopefully get down to what he really wants and I'll update the post after, with more clarity.

Comment: @Pete - no worries, your answer is still valid and should be the accepted answer, I was just adding in a small side note in relation to TwinTechs FastCell. However looking at the question again, they might not even be talking about that, I just picked that up from user1.

Comment: @AdamPedley From a short chat with him, after his first comment, he is focusing towards the FastCell I feel but its still not entirely clear until I have a further chat tomorrow.  There seems to be many questions with ambiguity at the moment.